# what will happen when the aof file for redis is too big, even after rewriting?

Tags: redis

I am reading something about redis persistence, right now two ways are available for keeping the redis persistence.

1. AOF
2. RDB

ok, i will skip the basic meanings of "AOF" and "RDB", I have a question about the "AOF", My question is "what will happen when the aof file for redis is too big, even after being rewrited ?", I have searched on google, but no result, somesone said the redis-server will fail to startup when the size of "AOF" file reach 3G or 4G. Could anyone can tell me ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't limit the size of `AOF` file. You can safely have a large `AOF` file. One of my Redis instance writes an `AOF` file with a size of `95G`, and it can reload the file successfully. Of course, it takes a very long time.

> somesone said the redis-server will fail to startup when the size of "AOF" file reach 3G or 4G

I'm not sure if the problem *someone* met, is because of the limit of file system. [For some old file system, the size of a single file CANNOT exceed `2G` or `4G`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_file_support). However, for modern file system, the limit has been removed.

Comment: wow! 95G! It must be a very long time when the redis is restarted. I am curious why not design an AOF based on RDB, if that's the case, the AOF file won't get too large and it will be faster when restart the redis o_O! Anyway, THX a lot :)